# How to deal with corresponding authors not sharing submission steps? (E.g. Peer reviews & Decisions)

Tags: peer-review, ethics, paper-submission, collaboration, correspondence

I am a 3rd-timer postdoc, and I often run into this issue. Over my career I have greatly benefitted personally of responsible peer review and participating in the elaboration of 'Response to Reviews'. Moreover I am very wary of publishing ethics, and open discussion of papers after publication.

This is often what happens: the 1st author of a paper where I am a co-author assigns a PI as last corresponding author. This PI is usually older and actually less invested in the project, but wishes to handle the submission. This person will however not share any correspondence with editors or submission files with authors other than the first (and I suspect even then not in full). I am thus left in the dark about discussions over papers where quite often I made a major part of the writing and experiments, and the only specialist about core topics being discussed.

I have tried asking for the details of peer review and was ignored, every time this happened. On a most recent case I received editorial notification of submission of same paper from two different journals within the time span of just 5 days, and now I fear somebody pulled a duplicate submission! This kind of attitude has made me reluctant of handing the position as corresponding authors to others, particularly to PIs, which is politically not good.

Thus I ask: How do others deal with such a situation?

UPDATE 1 (24.01.2018): I have just sent an email to the PI politely asking again for the peer reviews stating I will follow up with the journals if there is no reply.

UPDATE 2 (25.01.2018): First author responded informally providing the dates of all submission and general reasons for two rejections. The details didn't really add up, but given a casual tone perhaps it wasn't precise (e.g. I suspect this person is not aware of the difference of editor x reviewer). I still asked again for the Reviewers reports, and was left with the impression the 1st author did not (care to) see them either. She said she'll ask the PI.

In case I get no response I am not sure on how to proceed (e.g. if I want to see peer review from a previous journal).

Comment: "Is this widespread?" Hopefully not, it never occured to me, and I'd probably state very clearly how submissions should be handled. I'd stop collaborating if the problem persists.

Comment: I am already planning on stopping collaborating but have had already with three different groups. Either it is rather common or somehow my behaviour leads to such communication disruption...

Comment: @Scientist Were those three different groups at the same department or institute? I observed one department where this is common, but not in other places. For what it's worth, after this happened repeatedly with the same PI I not only stopped collaborating, but also informed the editor that manuscripts had been submitted without my (co-author) approval (amongst other problems). The editor too found the PI's behavior unacceptable.

Comment: With respect to the duplicate submission issue, while that's certainly possible, some journals engage in an "editorial review" process where the editor reads the paper and immediately rejects it based on some criteria (quality, relevance etc.) without ever sending it out for a full review. I don't know if this practice is common in your field but that might explain it.

Comment: @Mark Three different groups spamming two very distant countries. I am not adding too much detail to avoid an exposure but all are medium-tier institutions at 3rd-world countries, two in Latin America and the other in Asia. I get the feeling this is widespread and nobody says anything, and -- yet again -- I am the 'troublemaker'.

Comment: @TPM Yes, I think it is indeed quite possible. But I would not want to get penalised or badly exposed for sth I wasn't informed about, in case a duplicate submission was pulled. A relevant detail: I tried linking my ORCID number to both submissions via the Elsevier system using the submission notification emails, and found no submissions in the system. Why both seem to have been cancelled, and without any communication? Feels uncomfortable.

Comment: @silvado I am editing out then my more personal doubts and leaving just the question on how to deal with such situations.

Comment: Reputable journals often require a formal consent to publication (and sometimes a copyright agreement) from all authors.  This could give you some leverage - you can make it known that you won't sign the consent unless you have had a chance to read all the reviews and approve the final version.

Comment: Based on this experience, have you tried having a conversation about submission process *before* beginning the collaboration?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Regarding signed documents, whilst I’ve seen it It is not common in my field. Usually it goes as “by submitting all agree in that” on a tick box. Regarding discussions prior to collaborating, I agree. However the work culture in such places is informal. In reality I settle collaboration with another postdoc who’s younger and friendly and get briefly introduced to the PI. Orders of authorship are usually not settled before having the results (may not develop), and sb may chose to rever a PI by making this person corresponding author. I don’t like it but it’s how it works.

Comment: @NateEldredge I do wonder how common it actually is for such a form to be required from all authors. I think I have only once had to sign such a form when a coauthor was the one submitting (this was for Transactions of the AMS), though I may just have forgotten about it again.

Comment: @NateEldredge Many reputable journals (e.g. IEEE and IOP journals for engineering and physics) require the copyright form to be signed just by the corresponding author, _on behalf_ of all authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have decided to post my final update on this as answer to anyone arriving here in the same situation.

The following line of response worked: I have written a formal email (in English, which is not our language of choice for communication) to the first author and PI asking again for the results of previous submissions and to be duly warned of future submissions. I implied (by stating I could just contact the journals but 'felt that was the role of the corresponding author') I'd contact journal editors if ignored for more than 5 days.

Within less than 12h the first author responded informally describing generally what had come out of previous submissions. I still asked (informally) for the peer reviews and she said she had to ask the corresponding author for it (PI, last author). By that I understood this 1st author had also not seen the result of peer review, and told her this was not fair on her as well.

Finally after 5 days the PI contacted me formally, and in English (unexpected because it is not easy for him to write in English) excusing for the time taken, informing any future submissions would be correctly reported, and attaching the results of previous peer reviews. I am formally thanking him for the attention given.

I cannot say how the PI feels about this (I now live on the other side of the planet) nor whether there will be further collaborations. Whatever the reasons, his response was appropriate, thus I am recommending this line of action. On a personal note, I would not have escalated this to the journal editors unless I was sure there was something else out of place.

Thanks to all for the suggestions given.